# using databse connection in functions to avoid max_user_connections and smooth performance

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

just now i switched to a new way of accessing database i wanted to know is it safe and smooth and does not lead to any errors

```
` function db_connect(){
$host = '';
$db_name = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_password = '';
$db = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8mb4";
$conn=new PDO($db, $db_user, $db_password);

return($conn) }
function some-work-1()
{
$conn = db_connect();
$select = $conn ->prepare("SELECT data FROM `table`;");
$select->execute();
$conn=null;

}
function some-work-2()
{
$conn = db_connect();
$select = $conn ->prepare("SELECT data FROM `table`;");
$select->execute();
$conn=null;

}

`
```

I wanted to know is this a good way of accessing and closing db connection

Comment: 1) you cannot use dashes in function names, and 2) this won't solve your issue, and will actually make it worse by opening up new connections. You need to either raise your max_user_connections, get a new host that allows more user connections, or fix your queries so they don't take too long and hog the database.

Comment: It's best to open a database connection only ones when you execute a script. Closing is not that important, you can do it, but it is not necessary because it will close automatically when the script ends.

Comment: You should pass the connection through a parameter, function somework1($conn) and then use it inside

Comment: so closing connection is not necessary and if i pass $conn for each function is a good way  and i can't increase my max_user_connections as i am on shared hosting and i have less than 1k users

Comment: Each function call will be much slower.  Whether that slows down your app too much is a separate question.

Comment: If you are really hitting max_connections, look at your code and decide why the "page" is taking so long to render.  Maybe you can (1) quickly read all the data from the database (using only one Connect), (2) close the connection, (3) then slowly render the page.